# Get the element.values from querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-selectors

querySelectorAll(".blah") returns an array of elements. I want an array of each element's .value instead. Fastest way to do that?

Comment: `Array.prototype.map`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) on the results of [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get an array of values:

```js
const result = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.blah'), ({ value }) => value);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<input class="blah" value="1">
<input class="blah" value="2">
<input class="blah" value="3">
<input class="blah" value="4">
```